# can not choose website in advanced pricing

Tags: magento2, multi-website, advanced-pricing

I want use the advanced pricing set different price for different website.I have multiple websites,but in advanced pricing setting from I can just select one website——All Websites.Why? How can I fix it? Thanks very much.

[image]

actuary I have multiple websites
[image]

Comment: by the way,My version is 2.2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have change price attribute setting to Website from global.

```
Goto admin>Stores>Configuration>Catalog>Catalog>Price.
```

Then change the field's **Catalog Price Scope** to **Website**.

**After that Don't forget to Do Cache flush and indexing.**

[image]

Comment: thanks for responde,I tried that,but in that way, I can just set normal price,and can not add tier price any more.I prefer to use tier price,can I do that?

Comment: my bad, it's shown now,thanks very much

Comment: what was the problem cache or indexing?

Comment: yes,most likely is the indexing,thanks a lot